# Angular 5 Validators.required only in specific condition

Tags: angular, forms

I am creating a pretty complicated form. I want to set required value in my textarea control only if user select specific value from select control. For now I subscribe to select control, so every times it's value change it check if the selected value is 1 or not.

```
    onChanges(): void {
       this.form.controls['D5'].valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
           if(changes == 1){
               this.form.controls['ND5'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
           }
       });
    }
```

D5 is a my custom select and ND5 is my custom textarea. I want to set validator to required on ND5 only if user select the value 1 from select.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for my bad english. I want to make textarea(ND5 ) as required value on my reactive form only when user select value 1 from select (D5).

Comment: See this working example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgavbn?file=src/app/required-conditional-expression.component.ts, I have applied a rxweb validator for conditional validation. for conditional validation enter the value in D5 '1' then 'ND5' control will automatically required without writing custom code. Please let me know if you need know indetail about this solution.

Comment: It's what I asked.

Answer (score 0):

When data from D5 differ of 1, ND5 control will be disabled.

```
onChanges(): void {
       this.form.controls['D5'].valueChanges.subscribe(changes => {
           if(changes !== 1){
               this.form.controls['ND5'].disable();
           }
       });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's wasn't what I asked. Probably I explain it not that well.